# Anchor link in iOS

Tags: asp.net, html, ios

My anchor link works great on all platforms, IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari for Windows but for some reason it doesn't want to work on Safari for iOS. Here is the link:

```
<li><a id="fooId" href="http://foo.aspx">Main</a></li>
```

When I click the link, the page does not redirect. However, If you hold the button down and open it in a new tab it seems to work. Any ideas what would be causing this. Thanks.

Comment: Is the site https? If so that won't work. Either way I'd remove the http: from the path. The browser will resolve that to whichever is needed.

Comment: Yeah, the "mouse over" type of thing that you use on the desktop will not work well in iOS. Easily the most common problem with websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution and thought I would post it. iOS devices do not like any onmouse or mouse over events. Turning of JavaScript fixes this problem.